# How to display the number “12” in the format of “0000012”

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to display the number “12”  in the format of “0000012” Using SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you just want the number 12 then

```
SELECT '0000012'
```

else if it is a number you need to display with 7 digits:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000'+CONVERT(nvarchar,FieldValue),7)
```

More info on the question would help.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @Val INT
DECLARE @Length INT

SELECT  @Val = 12,
        @Length = 7

SELECT  REPLICATE('0',@Length - LEN(CAST(@Val AS VARCHAR(MAX)))) + CAST(@Val AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

[REPLICATE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx)

> Repeats a string value a specified
>   number of times.

Comment: Why not RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', @length) + CAST(@Val AS VARCHAR(8000)), @length)? Why test for LEN?

Comment: @gbn, I thought to just replicate the missing paddings. So if you have 100, it will only replicate 4 zeros, and 1000, only 3 and so on. Does that seem like a problem that I am missing?

Comment: no problem, I just wondered. The OCD bit of me dislikes doing stuff twice (2 x CAST)...

Answer (score 1):

The shortest answer that probably also works best is just

```
SELECT RIGHT(10000000+ @Val, @Length)
```

e.g.

```
SELECT RIGHT(10000000+ NumColumn, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got a server to test with, but you should be able to use the following in your SQL:

```
'RN ' + RIGHT(CAST(auto_id AS VarChar) + '000000', 6)
```

eg:
Code:

```
SELECT 'RN ' + RIGHT(CAST(auto_id AS VarChar) + '000000', 6)
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not efficient but will work for your case -

```
DECLARE @num int
DECLARE @totalChar int

SET @num = 12
SET @totalChar = 10

SELECT right('0000000000' + CONVERT(varchar, @num), @totalChar)
```

Output -

```
000000012
```

Answer (score 0):

This should easily port to other SQLs:

```
SELECT
   REVERSE(CAST(REVERSE(CAST(CAST(12 AS INTEGER) AS VARCHAR(7))) + '000000' AS CHAR(7)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR(12, 7), ' ', '0')
```